# How do we show a page from our app but using a custom domain owned by a user

Tags: dns, cname

We host an angular app (e.g. render.our-app.com) hosted on now/zeit. This app allows a user to show a presentation. The presentationId needs to be included in the path e.g. https://render.our-app.com/. We are looking to be able use a custom domain owned by the user, to show a presentation we no redirects.

So for example, the user has a domain (website.mycompany.com) and we want to show the presentation under that custom domain but using our app.

website.mycompany.com => render.our-app.com/12345 (12345 = presentationId)

We are not sure how to do this properly. We tried to use a cname but we get an error saying:
404: NOT_FOUND
Code: DEPLOYMENT_NOT_FOUND

(The error is very now/zeit specific)

We thought that http://website.mycompany.com/12345 might work.

We are not sure how to do this :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The steps involved probably would be:

1. Set up a virtual host on your server for website.mycompany.com (or maybe use a `ServerAlias` directive if you are on Apache. This is where your app will be hosted.
2. Edit the host file of the computer that will be used for the presentation, in that host file you add an entry for website.mycompany.com, that points to the IP address of your server. By doing so, you bypass the normal DNS resolution process. Rather than connect to the 'true' address, the PC will connect to your demo server.
3. There is a gotcha: SSL. You can create a self-signed certificate on the server, and then you add it to the list trusted certificates on the client (demo PC). This can be done the first time you launch your browser and get an alert about the self-signed certificate.